Visualizing charge densities using VESTA
I am calculating excited many-body states, such as excitons or trions, in two-dimensional semiconductors. I obtain their energies and expansion coefficients. For each state I have a code that calculates the density on a real-space grid obtained by squaring the many-body wave function of that given state. I now want to compare for example the first bright exciton state's real-space density with its accompanying bright trion real-space density.
I am visualizing both densities in VESTA, but I am unsure how to choose the isosurface value correctly in order to keep both figures comparable. Can someone explain to me what to look out for, because for example the Bohr radius found, heavily depends on the chosen isosurface value.
